# DisplayAccountInformation Outlook VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I would like to use the code from the class `DipslayAccountInformation` in a Windows Form project. ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.account))

If I put the code directly in the event button click form the main class, I have no problems.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
code
```

But I would like to use it from the class.  How do I do that?  How do I call the code from the class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: `DipslayAccountInformation` Is not a class, it is a method written by the example author. You are free to copy it and use it in your own application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to use it as a class from the click event behind the button on my form.
Found the answer (see below).

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim item = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
Sample.DisplayAccountInformation(item)
End Sub
End Class